# БД WP записи содержимого собственных метабоксов?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Здравствуйте
Собственно имеем свой тип записи, в нем имеем свой метабокс, в метабоксе поле - значение. Вопрос в том куда WP пишет эти данные в своей БД

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все зависит от разработчика, который придумал новый тип записи. Обычно хранят в таблице `wp_postmeta` при помощи функций `*_post_meta()`. Однако ничто не мешает хранить эти данные, например, в отдельной таблице, в файлах, или во внешнем хранилище

Comment: Да это ответ спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел
они хранятся в таблице postmeta